# How can I control the transition animation during reload of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Once a UIButton is clicked, the contents of a UITableView are changed by UITableView.reloadData() method.

What I want to do further is to change is reloading animation. I want the data to change immediately. Currently, the animation is the same as "Cross Dissolve" of trasition of view controllers; the former one fades out and then the reloaded data slightly shows up.

I cannot find such option to change animation in attributes inspector. How can I handle this problem if I can? Does is need to be managed programmatically?

It would be great if you give me some clues in Swift, not Objective C.

Comment: Always show some code you are trying.

Comment: Go in google and search with this line "uitableview reloaddata animation swift" you will get lots of stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :-

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections)
let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: range)
self.tableView.reloadSections(sections, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

and `.Automatic` , `.Left`, `.Right`, `.Bottom` , `.Top` , `.Fade` etc are the default Animations

Comment: There are several options to change its animation but nothing makes the table changes immediately though. Even 'None' doesn't work properly; if the numbers of rows in the former table and the latter are different, it looks like the rows move